# Canva how to set specific percantage?

Tags: html, css, canvas

i'm working on a spinner i am stuck on how to set specific percentage to the spinner.

Here is my demo => https://jsfiddle.net/fmvucqno/

inside `options` variable i have `10%` and `90%` i want to achieve `10%` fill and `90%` fill on the usernames.

```html
<input type="button" value="spin" style="float:left;" id='spin'/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<body style="background-color: white">

<script>
    var options = [
        [
            '@david',
            '10%',
        ],
        [
            '@burn',
            '90%'
        ]
    ];

    var startAngle  = 0;
    var arc         = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
    var spinTimeout = null;

    var spinArcStart  = 10;
    var spinTime      = 0;
    var spinTimeTotal = 0;

    var ctx;

    document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

    function byte2Hex(n)
    {
        var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F, 1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F, 1);
    }

    function RGB2Color(r, g, b)
    {
        return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
    }

    function getColor(item, maxitem)
    {
        var phase     = 0;
        var center    = 128;
        var width     = 127;
        var frequency = Math.PI * 2 / maxitem;

        red   = Math.sin(frequency * item + 2 + phase) * width + center;
        green = Math.sin(frequency * item + 0 + phase) * width + center;
        blue  = Math.sin(frequency * item + 4 + phase) * width + center;

        return RGB2Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    function drawRouletteWheel()
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        if (canvas.getContext)
        {
            var outsideRadius = 200;
            var textRadius    = 160;
            var insideRadius  = 125;

            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.lineWidth   = 2;

            ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
            {
                var angle     = startAngle + i * arc;
                ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.save();
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
                ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
                ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
                ctx.fillStyle     = "black";
                ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
                ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
                var text = options[i];
                ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
                ctx.restore();
            }

            //Arrow
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    function spin()
    {
        spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
        spinTime       = 0;
        spinTimeTotal  = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
        rotateWheel();
    }

    function rotateWheel()
    {
        spinTime += 30;
        if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal)
        {
            stopRotateWheel();
            return;
        }
        var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
        startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        drawRouletteWheel();
        spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
    }

    function stopRotateWheel()
    {
        clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
        var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
        var arcd    = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
        var index   = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
        var text = options[index]
        ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function easeOut(t, b, c, d)
    {
        var ts = (t /= d) * t;
        var tc = ts * t;
        return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
    }

    drawRouletteWheel();
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rojo thank you for the answer, i tried to keep it as minimal possible. Right now when i run the snippet both users have `50%` i want to be able to modify that, so one user has `%10` and other one has `90%`

Answer (score 1):

Although some options are set up for the different people, which include the percentage they should occupy, these are not actually used.

The arc is calculated to be equal for all users - `Math.PI / (options.length / 2)`

Instead we need to use the value given in the option for that user, and we have to gradually add to the start angle to know where to start the next arc.

Here's the snippet with the changes:

```js
    var options = [
        [
            '@david',
            '10%',
        ],
        [
            '@burn',
            '90%'
        ]
    ];

    var startAngle  = 0;
    var arc         = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
    var spinTimeout = null;

    var spinArcStart  = 10;
    var spinTime      = 0;
    var spinTimeTotal = 0;

    var ctx;

    document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

    function byte2Hex(n)
    {
        var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F, 1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F, 1);
    }

    function RGB2Color(r, g, b)
    { 
        return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
    }

    function getColor(item, maxitem)
    {
        var phase     = 0;
        var center    = 128;
        var width     = 127;
        var frequency = Math.PI * 2 / maxitem;

        red   = Math.sin(frequency * item + 2 + phase) * width + center;
        green = Math.sin(frequency * item + 0 + phase) * width + center;
        blue  = Math.sin(frequency * item + 4 + phase) * width + center;

        return RGB2Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    function drawRouletteWheel()
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        if (canvas.getContext)
        {
            var outsideRadius = 200;
            var textRadius    = 160;
            var insideRadius  = 125;

            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.lineWidth   = 2;

            ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';
      var angle = startAngle;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
            {  arc = Math.PI * Number(options[i][1].replace('%','')) / 50;
                ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.save();
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
                ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
                ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
                ctx.fillStyle     = "black";
                ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
                ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
                var text = options[i];
                ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
                ctx.restore();
        
                angle += (i+1) * arc;
            }

            //Arrow
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    function spin()
    {
        spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
        spinTime       = 0;
        spinTimeTotal  = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
        rotateWheel();
    }

    function rotateWheel()
    {
        spinTime += 30;
        if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal)
        {
            stopRotateWheel();
            return;
        }
        var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
        startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        drawRouletteWheel();
        spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
    }

    function stopRotateWheel()
    {
        clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
        var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
        var arcd    = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
        var index   = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
        var text = options[index]
        ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function easeOut(t, b, c, d)
    {
        var ts = (t /= d) * t;
        var tc = ts * t;
        return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
    }

    drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="spin" style="float:left;" id='spin'/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```